# Undefined offset: 1 error for laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

I have some validation on my form in laravel to ensure the gift the user is claiming is one assigned to their campaign with the below code

```
'gift_id' => 'required|int|exists:gifts,campaign_id,' . \Auth::user()->campaign->id,
```

But on form submission I am getting the following error

> ErrorException in ValidatesAttributes.php line 721:
>       Undefined offset: 1

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the exists rule is meant to check

Comment: @apokryfos It's to check if something exists...

Comment: @Ian not in the abstract, in this particular case

Comment: It basically queries that the gift with the campaign_id is the same as the campaign id of the user. (Ensuring that a user can only claim a gift which is relevant to their campaign)

Comment: @user6073700 i don't think `exists` would do that for you, you probably need a custom rule.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Exists allow where clauses as well like the above, it just concatenates the condition from the Auth::user campaign relationship

Comment: Are you using a Request to handle the validation? If so fluent rules may be up your alley. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/1310/validation/9670/other-validation-approaches#t=201703301054121552488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a more custom exists rule. According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists) exists as a string can only handle the existence of a specific input value in the specific column:

```
'gift_id' => [
    'required',
    'int',
    Rule::exists('gifts')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('campaign_id', \Auth::user()->campaign->id);
    }),
],
```

or something to this effect.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, where does the above code go? Thanks for the help

Comment: Instead of your current rules. This is another way of writing `'gift_id' => 'required|int|exists:gifts,campaign_id,' . \Auth::user()->campaign->id,` (more or less)

Comment: It's working mate, just forgot to include the Rule class, thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 11):

The Laravel application I'm currently working on started to throw that exception. In my case, the issue was slightly different. This was my original code:

```
// ...

'extension_id' => [
    'nullable',
    'int',
    Rule::exists('extensions,id'),
],

// ...
```

I added that `,id` to the table name hoping that the correct column name was used when the framework checks the value existence. However, it didn't work as expected. I got that exception from `Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes` class.

> Undefined offset: 1

After some attempts, I finally was able to overcome the error by passing two arguments to the rule, instead of a single string:

```
Rule::exists('extensions', 'id'),
```

I know that's not the same case as the OP, but I guess it can help others that reach this same question as I did.

Comment: this saved me with the same error and solution on a call to `Rule::unique`

Comment: Weird that it isn't represented this way in the documentation. Thanks a bunch!